# CSS Hide class/ID depending on other class being active

Tags: css

I have a menu bar that shows in 1 state when page loads, as soon as you scroll down the menu bar shrinks and is given a class of `.roll_activated` which controls height and sizing.

I have a div that I would only like to show when the `.roll_activated` is not `active`

I'm missing something with my code here:

```
.roll_activated:HLinfobox{display:none !important;}
```

The div I want to hide has a class of `HLinfobox`

Comment: You need to show your HTML. `:HLinfobox` is definitely incorrect. The class selector is `.`

Comment: _"I'm missing something with my code here:"_ Missing what? What did you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .roll_activated is not active

There is no such thing in CSS, but what you can do is nest elements and then show or hide them depending on their parent's state.

So, if the div that you want to show only when the menu bar has a class `.roll_activated` attached, you can do this (assuming `#div` is *the* div that you wanna toggle).

```
#div {
  display: none;
}
.roll_activated #div {
  display: block;
}
```

Assuming HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="roll_activated">
  <div id="div"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGgygW

Comment: thank you that's what I was trying to do. I just inversed the display so it hides when roll_activated is active.